# Estimate PDSI value in GEE for a specific shapefile area

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-statistics

How can I estimate PDSI value in GEE for a specific shapefile area? I am having some problem in the code.

```
var feature = ee.FeatureCollection(table);
Map.addLayer(feature, {}, 'My Polygon');
var startDate = ee.Date('2005-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2005-12-31');
// Load the necessary image collections
var temperature = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/ORNL/DAYMET_V4"),
    precipitation = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/ORNL/DAYMET_V4"),
    elevation = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");


// Filter the image collections to the desired time range and region
temperature = temperature.filterBounds(feature)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate).select('tmax');
precipitation = precipitation.filterBounds(feature)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate).select('prcp');
elevation = elevation.clip(feature);

// Calculate the monthly temperature and precipitation averages
var monthlyTemp = temperature.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.median(),
  sharedInputs: true
}));
var monthlyPrecip = precipitation.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.median(),
  sharedInputs: true
}));

// Calculate the water balance variables
var tmax = monthlyTemp.select('tmax');
var pet = tmax.multiply(0.003 + 0.007 * elevation).subtract(0.26);
var ppt = monthlyPrecip.select('prcp');

// Calculate the PDSI
var pdsi = ee.Image().expression(
  '(((0.897 * (pet - ppt)) + 0.166 * ((pet - ppt) ** 1.5)) / ' +
  '(((12 * 0.897 * (pet - ppt)) / (tmax - 32)) + 1))', {
    pet: pet,
    ppt: ppt,
    tmax: tmax
  }).rename('pdsi');

var visParams = {
  min: -5,
  max: 5,
  palette: [
    'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue'
  ],
  value: 'pdsi' // Specify the name of the band to use for visualization
};

Map.addLayer(pdsi, visParams, 'PDSI');
// Check for any errors or missing parameters
print(pdsi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are related to the following syntax in your code. There are several errors that I found out.

```
// Calculate the water balance variables
var tmax = monthlyTemp.select('tmax');
var pet = tmax.multiply(0.003 + 0.007 * elevation).subtract(0.26);
var ppt = monthlyPrecip.select('prcp');

// Calculate the PDSI
var pdsi = ee.Image().expression(
  '(((0.897 * (pet - ppt)) + 0.166 * ((pet - ppt) ** 1.5)) / ' +
  '(((12 * 0.897 * (pet - ppt)) / (tmax - 32)) + 1))', {
    pet: pet,
    ppt: ppt,
    tmax: tmax
  }).rename('pdsi');
```

So, I modify above lines as follows and my [GEE code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c37d2faf7cb235fbc512395a8e90a53) produced a result without any error.

```
// Calculate the water balance variables
var tmax = monthlyTemp.select('tmax_mean');

var pet = ee.Image().expression(
  'tmax*(0.003 + 0.007 * elevation)-0.26', {
  'tmax': tmax,
  'elevation': elevation
  }
  
).rename('pet');

var ppt = monthlyPrecip.select('prcp_mean');

// Calculate the PDSI
var pdsi = ee.Image().expression(
  '(((0.897 * (pet - ppt)) + 0.166 * ((pet - ppt) ** 1.5)) / (((12 * 0.897 * (pet - ppt)) / (tmax - 32)) + 1))', {
  'pet': pet,
  'ppt': ppt,
  'tmax': tmax
  }).rename('pdsi');
```

The result can be observed in the following picture; where I assumed a table geometry in USA area (because you don't provide one):

[image]

However, you should review the validity of the formulas because the PDSI values are only varying approximately between -2.6573 and -2.3061. This seems a strange behavior.